# Collision 2D detection not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, detection

I got this straight from the unity website and I have box colliders on all of my objects but for some reason nothing is printing when the cars connect.

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "car") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("make a sound");
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `OnCollisionEnter2D`. capitalization matters.

Comment: It is `OnCollisionEnter2D` not `onCollisionEnter2D` Flagged to close as " typographical error".